# Additions of large integers in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, integer-arithmetic

I met a very weird situation in JavaScript, which is that

```
9007199254740992 + 1 = 9007199254740992
9007199254740992 + 3 = 9007199254740996
```

Does anyone know the reason for this? Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Nothing weird about it, commonly known limitation of 64bit floating point ... see `Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER` == `9007199254740991` - any integer maths above that value (or below the negative of that) is not going to be accurate at all - by the way, that number is 2^53 - 1

Comment: @JaromandaX I see. Thanks so much!